# Perform calculations on subset of dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df in which I have a categorical column, and then various columns which are numeric - I need to calculate various values but on the subset of the df where the category is the same:

```
Type | num1 | num2
 a   | 10   | 10 
 a   | 5    | 10
 a   | 1    | 30 
 b   | 5    | 10
...
```

Here I would like to calculate the % that is each value makes up from the total of that type

So the output would be:

```
Type | num1 | num2 | num2_pct
 a   | 10   | 10   | 20
 a   | 5    | 10   | 20
 a   | 1    | 30   | 60
...
```

This calculation would occur for each value in the `type` column.

I have tried to use `df.loc` and writing a loop, creating a new DF and then merging them - but this cannot be the correct way!

Comment: the num1_pct looks more like calculated values based on num2 column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run it individually, or use a pipe to get the results :

```
#pipe

df["num1_pct"] = (df.groupby("Type")
                    .pipe(lambda x: x.num2.transform(lambda x: x).div(x.num2.transform("sum")).mul(100)))

       Type num1    num2    num1_pct
   0    a   10      10      20.0
   1    a   5       10      20.0
   2    a   1       30      60.0
   3    b   5      10       100.0

#individually, and in my own opinion, cleaner : 

grouping = df.groupby("Type")

df["num2_pct"] = df.num2 * 100 / grouping.num2.transform("sum")
```

Comment: Could you please explain the second version - I am struggling to understand how that works since grouped is of a different shape?

Comment: transform ensures that the aggregation is replicated for each row. Try out the grouping on its own, you will see that it gives you [50,50,50,10] which matches the number of rows and is equivalent to the sum of num2 for each group.